# Como criar um evento para vários elementos?

Tags: javascript

**Função:**

```
document.getElementsById("nome").onblur = function(){
//algum código aqui
}
```

veja que no código acima só consigo executar apenas para um único elemento, eu gostaria de explicitar tipo 3 eventos específicos, ou para todos os tipo de um elemento, exemplo com document.getElementsByTagName

**O que eu não gostaria é:**

```
<input type="text" onblur="nomedafuncao(this)">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça algo para selecionar todos os elementos que deseja e depois adicione o *event listener* a eles.

No exemplo, eu seleciono todos os `inputs` e adiciono o evento `onblur`.

```js
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for(let el of elementos) {
  el.onblur = function(){
    console.log('yay');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```